# How I can advertise my browser game

Tags: browser-based-games, marketing

I developed a browser-based game. It's a Multiplayer Business Strategy Game. Currently I am unable to find a place where I can advertise my game. My main requirements are :

1. I can only pay via Credit Card. No Paypal. Just tell me which ad company accepts credit cards.
2. I also have quite a limited budget.

Also, I want to know is their is any rating / review website for my type of game?

Comment: Do you really think that this question is suitable for this website? I understand that it's game related but the question overall does on pertain to **game** development.

Comment: I removed the link to make this question seem too localized. (since where to advertise *your* game is far too localized) @AustinBrunkhorst I think advertising is on topic, I believe it falls under: **project management (testing, team management, scheduling, publishing, etc)**. But this question is asking for a list, which is discouraged.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that the best option is to use Facebook ads or Google ads. I have had pretty good success using FB for advertising because you can set a daily spending limit and you can target your (fairly close) audience. I would also suggest a facebook page for your game.

I personally am not a huge FB fan but I can vouch that doing that really helps.

Answer (score 1):

Let me ask you: How do you intend to make money with your game?

If your game just have advertisement as the revenue source, I ***highly*** discourage you to invest even $0.01 in marketing. You will spend money foolishly. I know because I've been there.

Why? You will expend at least $0.10 / click. Suppose that 1,000 users click in ads you set to acquire users. You expended $100.

Now you must be aware that the eCPM of ads inside your game will pay you at most $25/1,000 clicks. But usually it's around $0.10/1,000  clicks.

If all acquired users clicked in the ads inside your game, you would get at most $25. A loss of $75.

But notice that the CTR (how many clicks per 100 users apps/games usually get) is around 2%.

So, you can expect that from 1,000 users you will get around 20 clicks. For the highest eCPM ($25/1,000 clicks) you would earn $0.50. A loss of $99.50.

Let me repeat once more: only invest money in marketing *if* your application has in-app purchase in it *and* you expect to earn much more than you will invest.

Note: for in-app purchase, it's expected that around 7% of active user base will expend money. All other users won't expend anything.

Comment: Answering questions that happen to include links to your services is OK (as long as you clearly state they belong to you), answering questions *just* to promote your services is discouraged and not an appropriate use of this site. Thanks.

Comment: @Byte56 How can I contact you? Thanks

Comment: You can contact me in chat when you have enough reputation. Just use @Byte56 in chat to ping me.

Comment: I edited the answer you deleted but I'm unable to put it back. Can you please take a look at it? Also, I cannot earn reputation because system doesn't allow me to post anything.

Comment: You earn reputation from having answers *or* questions you have posted up-voted. You can also earn reputation from existing answers if you have been otherwise temporarily prevented from answering questions. See the [help] for more.